# How to convert this SQL query to an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch querying, so I'm a little lost on how to convert this SQL query to an Elasticsearch query:

```
SELECT time_interval, type, sum(count)  
FROM test  
WHERE  (&start_date <= t_date <= &end_date) 
GROUP BY time_interval, type
```

I know I can use the "**range**" query to set parameters for **gte and lte**, but if there's a clearer way to do this, that would be even better. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

My elasticsearch is setup to have an index: **"test"** with type: **"summary"** and contains JSON documents that have a few fields:

**t_datetime**

**t_date**

**count**

**type**

*t_id**

The IDs for these JSON documents are the t_date concatenated with the t_id values

Comment: Please mention the mapping of your index.

Comment: I don't see the same name of fields used in your SQL query as in the list of fields you've mentioned in your edit. Can you please edit your question so that the type of each field you used in the SQL query is clear?

Comment: @bsarkar hopefully it's clearer now!

Comment: Is `time_interval` the same as `t_datetime`?

Comment: I've tried to answer your question. Can you test if it fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, `t_datetime` is the same as `time_interval`, you can use the query below:

```
POST trans/summary/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "filtered_results": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "t_date": {
                  "gte": "2015-05-01",
                  "lte": "2015-05-30"
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "time_interval_type_groups": {
               "terms": {
                  "script": "doc['t_datetime'].value + '_' + doc['type'].value",
                  "size": 0
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "sum_of_count": {
                     "sum": {
                        "field": "count"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query is making use of scripts. On newer versions of Elasticsearch, dynamic scripting is disabled by default. To enable dynamic scripting, follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting).